# Upgrading macOS SSD to a larger size SSD and fully utilizing space on the new SSD when restoring from a backup

Tags: macos, mac, ssd, backup, macbook

I'm upgrading SSD on a MacBook Air 2012 with Mojave from 64GB to 500GB. I've successfully cloned and swapped the drives (using Ubuntu USB stick and `dd` command). Now the MacOS boots and works as well as before, but I have a 500GB drive with a 60GB partition on it.

I tried to use Disk Utility to resize it to 500GB, but it failed, perhaps because there's a also a Recovery Partition next to it.

If I do a Time Machine Backup now, then repartition the drive, reinstall the OS and do a restore form the Time Machine Backup, will I still end up with a 60GB partition? Is there a better way to resize it?

Comment: “My question, if I do a Time Machine Backup now, then re-partition the drive, reinstall the OS and do a restore form the Time Machine Backup, will I still end up with a 60GB partition? Is there a better way to resize it?” If you generally work with the logic of copying data rather than restoring a portion, the partition size will be the size of the destination rather than the source. If you do a restore that just really clones a partition, the 60GB archive will be restored to 60GB on the larger drive and leave you tons of dead space. Good work figuring this out for yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, yes, it's possible. I now have a single 500GB partition after restoring it from a 60GB Time Machine backup. Before restoring it though, I did a secure SSD erase, then made a single 500GB APFS partition. So the whole cloning thing was redundant.